# libavformat.so cannot be found

Tags: python, pyffmpeg

I have problem with running pyfmpeg that when I try to import code below it gives error:

> libavformat.so can not found

How can I solve this problem I could not find enough information about it.Thanks..

Operating Systen: Ubuntu 12.04
Python version: 2.7

```
import pyffmpeg

stream = pyffmpeg.VideoStream()
stream.open('test.mp4')
image = stream.GetFrameNo(0)
image.save('firstframe.png')
```

**Problem Solved:**
I downloaded libs from here http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libavformats52 and copy to /usr/lib/

But new problem exist now it gives error:

> wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Comment: I bet you are on a 64bit system, and you installed a 32 bit lib. You better install libavformat, using apt-get.

Comment: Yes friend you are right, however I thought if I install ffpmeg, libavformat.so also be installed, but not so. How can I compile this library externally. I examined and tried Synaptic Package Manager but not achieved. Actually pyffmpeg needs libavformat.so.52 however in synaptic manager there is libavformat.so.53, may be this is the problem. I will look it.

Answer (score 2):

This may not work until all depended libraries be installed, so
install ffmpeg library with `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

This will install all dependenties of 'ffmpeg encoding/decoding' what may needs the pyffmpeg library.

Comment: I have already installed ffmpeg but libavformat.so has not been installed.